# Add Dynamic Element to Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using a widget to show some related posts.

I am inserting the code directly into the template as follows

```
<?php
$args = array(
"post_author_url" => "no",
"post_include" => "3456",
"layout_mode" => "multi_column","layout_num_cols" => "3");
special_recent_posts($args);
?>
```

However, I want to dynamically fill the 'post_include' field with an userID that I echo in as follows `<?php echo get_user_meta($userID,'member_owner',true); ?>`

So the code I am thinking would look something like this

```
<?php
$args = array(
"post_author_url" => "no",
"post_include" => "<?php echo get_user_meta($userID,'member_owner',true); ?>",
"layout_mode" => "multi_column","layout_num_cols" => "3");
special_recent_posts($args);
?>
```

I don't know how to add this dynamic ID to the array as what i am doing does not work.

looking for some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"post_include" => get_user_meta($userID, 'member_owner', true),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$args = array(
"post_author_url" => "no",
"post_include" => get_user_meta($userID,'member_owner',true),
"layout_mode" => "multi_column","layout_num_cols" => "3");
special_recent_posts($args);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest php opening tags.

Do it without reopening the php tags and use your function directly:

`"post_include" => get_user_meta($userID,'member_owner',true);`

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to set it afterwards you can simply do:

```
$args['post_include'] = get_user_meta($userID, 'member_owner', true);
```